# Error 500 when web.config is present in microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2 Windows container

Tags: asp.net, powershell, docker, windows-container

I'm trying to get my ASP.NET site in a Windows Container (it cannot be moved to .NET Core just yet). When I just copied my app into inetpub\wwwroot I got an error 500. I even tried setting detailed errors and everything in the web.config  file but I still got the "same" error.

I tried removing files and commenting out my web.config until it began working again with no luck what so ever.

So I realized that even with an empty web.config the site fails. Right now I have a single default.html file which prints "Hello World!", everything works until I add an empty web.config in that directory.

This is driving me nuts!

1) Is there a way to see the real error or a better description of what's going on inside the container? I've tried with the Event Viewer (Get-EventLog) and the logs of the IIS with no luck.

2) What the heck is going on? Is this even related to my issue? Maybe a site with an empty web.config always fails :(

**EDIT**: My Dockerfile is irrelevant since I'm just firing up a container of the microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2 image.
`docker run -d -p 8888:80 microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2`
Once the container starts I get in with:
`docker exec -it mycontainer powershell`
Once inside I created the default.html file as follows:
`echo "Hello World!" > default.html`
If I then go to http://localhost:8888/default.html I see the right Hello World message. After that, I create a dummy web.config with the following:
`echo "" > web.config`
And when I refresh the default.html file I get the 500 error :(

Comment: Try failed request tracing logs.

Comment: Post your dockerfile

Comment: Check permissions of the folder you moved files to.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş thanks, do you happen to know where do I find them?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev thanks, I've thought about that and I played around with Get-Acl with no luck. Anyways, now I'm creating both files the same way

Comment: @GregorySuvalian thanks, I edited my question adding the steps I follow... right now there's no Dockerfile :(

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş installed the logs with `Add-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Tracing` and a new folder appeared at `c:\inetpup\logs\FailedReqLogFiles` but it is empty :(

Comment: Do following instead `echo "<configuration></configuration>" > web.config` looks like empty web.config is cause of the issue

Comment: just so everybody knows, my initial issue was due to the fact that I had rewrite rules in my web.config and urlrewriting was not installed ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web.config shall contain `configuration` element. Issue is not docker specific. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/configuration-element

Comment: yes! this did it, so I guess my original web.config file has some invalid tag... maybe using a feature not installed in windows server core :(